# Set some horizontal border in my table

Tags: tables

I have a big table and I want to put something, in order to divide the table in 3 parts.

Here is my table:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\begin{tabular}{|l|l||l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|}
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN} \\
\hline
Program & N & dim & p\_l & \#trees & max\_l & $\epsilon$ & miss & error & Speedup \\ \hline
\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
\hline
...


\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
...


\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline
\multirow{1}{*}{RKD} & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline
...

\end{tabular}
\end{large}
\end{center}
```

So, I want where I have left blank lines, to put something in order to separate the table (of course I could just create another table), I just want to see how it looks.

Comment: Why don't you use a `\multicolumn{10}{c}{} \tabularnewline` there as a separator?

Comment: I used that @ChristianHupfer, and the upper part closes, while the lower one is bold from above (has no border).

Comment: There definitely too much lines in it...

Comment: Do not use `l`eft aligned columns for numbers. Take a look to the `dcolumn` and `siunitx` packages for columns with decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses a `\multicolumn{10}{c}{}` as a separator, filled with a gray space between. The second example does not use colour separator.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xcolor}


\usepackage{colortbl}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{l|}}%
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN} \\
\hline
Program & N & dim & p\_l & \#trees & max\_l & $\epsilon$ & miss & error & Speedup \\ \hline
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
\hline
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{\cellcolor{lightgray}} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{\cellcolor{lightgray}} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}

\begin{center}
\large
\begin{tabular}{|*{10}{l|}}%
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{|c|}{Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN} \\
\hline
Program & N & dim & p\_l & \#trees & max\_l & $\epsilon$ & miss & error & Speedup \\ \hline
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
\hline
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6  \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}


\begin{center}
\large
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{*{10}{l}}%
\multicolumn{10}{c}{Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN} \\[2ex]
\hline
Program & N & dim & p\_l & \#trees & max\_l & $\epsilon$ & miss & error & Speedup \\ [2ex]
\hline
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 &                     & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & \multirow{-2}{*}{0} & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6  \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 &                     & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & \multirow{-2}{*}{0} & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
\hline
\multicolumn{10}{c}{} \tabularnewline
\hline
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 &  & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & \multirow{-2}{*}{0} & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{center}



\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Looks perfect! Can I get greedy and ask for another question? In my table, ε has the same value for some consecutive cells. Can I do something, so that that this specific field does not separated by the normal horizontal border?

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: What are the many `\multirow{1}` for?

Comment: @Bernard these came from my code. I don't remember why I have them there.

Comment: @G.Samaras: In my opinion, they're only here to have a  more verbose code…

Comment: @Bernard I removed one and the result didn't change, so you are probably right. Now I am eager to see if Mr. Hupfer has an answer to my meta-question.

Comment: I just remarked the `\begin{large}` ... stuff -- strange ;-)

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I was just thinking of that when you posted your comment:o)

Comment: In my table, ε has the some value, in two consecutive rows. However it is separated, with the one value belonging to 1st row and the second one to the 2nd row. I would like this filed (i.e. ε) to be in a common column, common for 1st and 2nd row. Did this help?

Comment: @G.Samaras: Something like in my updated version?

Answer (score 4):

[image: MWE]

Remove all vertical lines and horizontal lines within each part, so that two simple horizontal lines is enough to divide clearly the table in three parts.

Optionally, at the end of rows you can use some like `\\[2ex]` to add some vertical space.

I removed also the multicolumn and multirows cell. Maintain your table as simple as possible.

But it is better if you change the remaining `\hline`s by the appropriate commands of the package `booktabs`. Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\centering Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN\\[10pt]

\begin{tabular}{llllllllll}

\toprule

Program & N & dim & p\_l & \#trees & max\_l & $\epsilon$ & miss & error & Speedup \\

\midrule\addlinespace[2ex]

RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\

\midrule\addlinespace[2ex]

RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & 0 & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\

\midrule\addlinespace[2ex]

RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & 0 & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Of course, `\midrule` plus `\addlinespace[2ex]` is only a example, feel free to use only the rule, any other vertical space than 2ex (incluning  none),  or another types of rules. With the package `arydshln` you can use also custom dashed lines, so that you can type some  like:

```
\addlinespace[.2ex]\hdashline[3pt/5pt]\addlinespace[.2ex]
```

However, for a custom solid line + spacing is easier use `\specialrule` (from `booktabs` package). For example:

```
\specialrule{.3pt}{.3ex}{.3ex}
```

What is better is a matter of taste, but note that many editors and many TeX.SE users hate the tables with extra rules (me too, but the question was "set a boder"...)

Comment: Is `\addlinespace` necessary after a `\midrule`?

Comment: @Manuel Not at all, is completely optional.

Comment: Mmm… I know that, I meant that I think it's not necessary at all. You can add a midrule or space to differentiate parts of a table… but both? I think it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Manuel I agree, at least with `2ex`, but the MWE is only for demonstration purposes `:)`

Comment: I'd consider dropping the two middle midrules entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Some variations and improvements (to my eyes at least) with using a `caption`, the `S` column type for columns with a decimal comma and `\cmidrule`s where appropriate rather than `\midrule`s:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array, multirow, booktabs, caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{geometry}
\captionsetup{font = small, labelfont = sc}
\setlength\aboverulesep{1ex}
\setlength\belowrulesep{2ex}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}\centering
\caption{Performance of RKD-forest vs FLANN}

\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{S[table-format=3.3]}S[table-format=2.0]*{3}{c}S[table-format=1.3]S[table-format=1.4]S[table-format=4.1]}

\toprule

Program & {N} & {dim} & {p\_l} & {\#trees} & {max\_l} & {$\epsilon$} & {miss} & {error} & {Speedup} \\

\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{1-6}\cmidrule[\lightrulewidth]{8-10}

RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 &\multirow{6}{1em}[-3ex]{0} & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\
RKD & 1.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & & 0.22 & 0.001 & 218.6 \\

\cmidrule(lr){1-6}\cmidrule(r){8-10}

RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\
RKD & 10.000 & 10.000 & 2 & 4 & 2 & & 0.492 & 0.0015 & 3489.6 \\

\cmidrule(lr){1-6}\cmidrule(r){8-10}

RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.8 \\
RKD & 100.000 & 100 & 50 & 1 & 2 & & 0.568 & 0.0068 & 836.\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]